# Can I secure my Asp.net MVC using external JWT provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jwt

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 web application like: http://www.mmm.com and I need to use an **External JWT** (JSON Web Token) provider like http://www.example.com/token.
 This service will return (Token) if username and password are correct how to deal with it and **secure my controllers** and how to **check in every request that (Token) is correct**. I know that Asp.Net Identity providing built-in integration for the authentication services such as Facebook, Google, Microsoft Accounts and Twitter but not the custom external provider link.

Comment: `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt` - `UseJwtBearerAuthentication`